# How can i create pagination properly with List<IGrouping<string,Product>>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, pagination

I've this query that groups all the items via UniqueGroupId

```
result = ProductList1.Except(productlist3).Union(ProductList2).GroupBy(a => a.UniqueGroupId).OrderByDescending(a=>a.Key).ToList();
```

it returns a `List<IGrouping<string,Product>>`

It works ok, each product is properly grouped and when it finds an element that has not UniqueGroupId set, it returns back a megagroup with a null key that contains every products that haven't got a proper UniqueGroupId set.

This query results are then given to a View, that display content.

Now, since results are becoming bigger, i would like to implement a pagination in order to display content better, where each group is counted as 1 element of the page, except the group that has Key null, in this, every element of the group should be considered as 1 element.

I would like to use Skip and Take, but obviously the problem is that if i Skip(50) also all the elements contained in Key null are skipped and that is not what i would like to achieve..

How can i solve this? Thanks

Comment: How is the view display the result? Is the view taking grouped elements and then flattening it, before displaying it?

Comment: Are the involved `ProductList` variables in memory collections (e.g. `List<Product>`) or `IQueryable`s? Also what is the name of `Product` PK property (e.g. `Id`?) and type (e.g. `int`?)

Comment: @bazz, Yes, the View is taking List of grouped elements.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes,The variables are in memory, the type of PK of Product is a string. The name is Id

Comment: You cannot do paging as long as you're unioning these two lists in-memory. You need to complete both the union and the group by *at the database level*. Then, you can limit that result set accordingly to page through it. There's not enough info about your entities to tell you how to construct the query or even determine if it's possible. However, it may be better anyways to create a stored procedure for this, which then wouldn't require any specific API being exposed through your entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit challenging, but possible.

You need to (1) group by *composite key* in such a way that the non null `UniqueGroupId` generates a normal grouping while the null `UniqueGroupId` generates a single element grouping for each element, then (2) sort the groupings, (3) apply pagination, (4) flatten the result and (5) group it again by just `UniqueGroupId`:

```
var result = ProductList1.Except(productlist3).Union(ProductList2)
    .GroupBy(e => new { K1 = e.UniqueGroupId, K2 = e.UniqueGroupId == null ? e.Id : null }) // (1)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key.K1).ThenBy(g => g.Key.K2) // (2)
    .Skip(...).Take(...) // 3
    .SelectMany(g => g) // 4
    .GroupBy(e => e.UniqueGroupId); // 5
```

Comment: Hi ivan, i tried your solution and it seems to work! But, how can i retrieve the total number of pages with this approach?

Comment: You can store the part before the `Skip` in a variable, e.g. `var query = ...;`. Then you could use `var pageCount = query.Count(); var result = query.Skip(...)....;`

Answer (score 0):

Can you do some reordering of your groups? If so, consider this idea: put your largest group to the end of the collection and recalculate `skip` count. Here is example:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(p => p.UniqueGroupId).ToList();

var ordered = result.OrderBy(g => g.Key != null ? 0 : 1);

if (skip < result.Count - 1)
    return ordered.Skip(skip).Take(take);

return ordered.Last().Skip(skip - result.Count - 1)
    .Take(take).GroupBy(p => p.UniqueGroupId);
```

Comment: If i use this the elements returned will no longer be grouped, .SelectMany() is returning a IEnumerable<Product>, i would like to mantain elements grouped

Comment: @Oper please see my updated answer. Now it's return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Product>>`